# PutAll to the Map without messing with order

Tags: java, android, sorting, treemap

I have this simple method which is part of my `CustomBaseAdapter`

```
public void setDays(Map<String, SimplifiedDay> sortedDays) {            
    days.clear();   
    days.putAll(sortedDays);        
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Yeah, I'm populating `ListView` with a `Map`. The problem is, that sorted map comes to the method as `sortedDays`but after `putAll` the order is lost. I can't just do `days = sortedDays;` because the `BaseAdapter` would go nuts.

How to preserve the order here?

Comment: What is the class of 'days' ? HashMap is not ordered, but TreeMap is.

Comment: It's a TreeMap actually

Comment: A TreeMap with a custom Comparator ? Or is it using the default String Comparator ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using LinkedHashMap for your days class, not sure what it currently is.

Comment: LinkedHashMap will keep things in the order they were put in.  If you are using TreeMap then something must be wrong with the sorting you are using.